# Assigned value is garbage or undefined logic error in XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am updating our iPhone app to iOs4 and I ran into an issue "Pass-by-argument in function call is undefined" in the code

```
for (i = 0; i < self.numberOfSegments; i++) {
        [self setWidth:round(width[i]) forSegmentAtIndex:i];
}
```

Which is fair enough, width[i] hasn't been initialized.  Updating the code (below) however gives me this new error, "Assigned value is garbage or undefined".  Reading up on this I think that segWidth retains its value as garbage - is that correct and if so how do I clear it?

```
for (i = 0; i < self.numberOfSegments; i++) {
    float segWidth = (float)width[i];
    [self setWidth:round(segWidth) forSegmentAtIndex:i];
}
```

------------- EDIT ------------------

Thanks for the replies guys.  More information as follows;

A genericised version of the method is shown below as someFunction. I have removed the ugly cast but still see the "Assigned Value is Garbage or undefined" logic error for the line `segWidth = width[i];`

I agree it appears the value width[i] doesn't have clear initialisation, I am unsure if it's my lack of understanding of basic Obj-c float types or if there is a logic flaw in my assignment syntax?

```
- (void)someFunction
{
    unsigned int n = self.numberOfSegments;
    float width[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       width[i] = someFloatValue;
    }

    ...    

    for (i = 0; i < self.numberOfSegments; i++) {
       float segWidth = 0.0;
       segWidth = width[i];

       [self setWidth:round(segWidth) forSegmentAtIndex:i];
    }

}
```

Definition of setWidth is:

```
- (void)setWidth:(CGFloat)width forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment;         // set to 0.0 width to autosize. default is 0.0
```

Comment: What is the full method signature for `setWidth:forSegmentAtIndex:`? We need to see those types.

Comment: the fact that you're casting width[i] scares me.

Comment: Right - My apologies it's my second week in ObC/Cocoa & it's not my codebase. The method signature was

- (void)setWidth:(CGFloat)width forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment;

Casting was an attempt to get more definition on the unknown, retrospectively a futile hack. Thanks for the headsup!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are calling:

```
- (void)setWidth:(CGFloat)width forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment
```

And that *Pass-by-argument in function call is undefined* is actually the LLVM static analyzer error when you do Build and Analyze.  (Both rather important data points -- passing along exactly what you were doing and exactly what the output was is quite helpful).

And you say that `width[i]` hasn't been initialized.

Your fix of adding `float segWidth = (float)width[i]` very much should cause the analyzer to complain with ** Assigned value is garbage or undefined**.  You haven't actually set `width[i]` to anything.  I would suggest filing a bug against the static analyzer, though, because that first error message is really quite thoroughly obtuse.

As Joshua also said, that cast is really weird, too.  In general, in Objective-C you should very rarely have to use type casting and pretty much never use it on scalar types.

---

Consider the two loop counts:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
...
}


for (i = 0; i < self.numberOfSegments; i++) {
...
}
```

The static analyzer doesn't know that `n == self.numberOfSegments` and, thus, must assume that the second loop could loop longer than the first.   Now, you might say, "But I assigned `n = self.numberOfSegments` above?!"

You did, but that value could have changed between the first call and second call and, thus, the analyzer has correctly identified that you might be using an uninitialized value.

(Really, it should be saying that you might run off the end of the array, because that is the real risk).

Comment: Thanks bbum.  I have only recently joined the big boys from 10 years of scripting languages so I must apologise for my rudimentary explanation.  I have edited the question with further information, I am still a little unsure as to how to resolve this logic flaw?

Comment: Ahhh, bbum - you are a champion.  Thank you for taking the time to answer, that makes perfect sense (and it fixes the problem!) :)